# Pegar os registros do mês mais recente

Tags: mysql

Tenho uma tabela simples que armazena títulos e data de publicação, esta no formato DATE, e preciso pegar todos os registros do mês/ano mais recente.

```
select titulo, publicacao FROM teste1 ORDER BY publicacao DESC
```

Comment: Acho que sua resposta está [**aqui**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1479749/1244639) com o uso de `DATE_SUB`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Considerando o mês/ano mais recente dentro da tabela, é possível utilizar uma variável:

```
SET @ultimaData := (SELECT publicacao FROM teste1 ORDER BY publicacao DESC LIMIT 1);

SELECT titulo, publicacao FROM teste1 
WHERE YEAR(publicacao) = YEAR(@ultimaData) 
AND MONTH(publicacao) =  MONTH(@ultimaData);
```

Caso queira do mês/ano mais recente considerando o dia de hoje, pode substituir a variável por `now()`

```
SELECT titulo, publicacao FROM teste1 
WHERE YEAR(publicacao) = YEAR(now()) 
AND MONTH(publicacao) =  MONTH(now());
```

[**Exemplo no SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f5646a/1)

Comment: A primeira funcionou. Mas a segunda também deveria funcionar não?

Comment: @marcelo2605 postei um exemplo, está funcionando sim, porém ela busca mês/ano com relação o dia de hoje.

Comment: Então esta segunda query só irá funcionar se houver registros no mês atual?

Comment: Exato, só mês atual. Como não ficou muito claro sua dúvida inclui ambas formas.

Comment: Obrigado. A primeira query resolve o meu problema.

Comment: Provavelmente existem outras formas de fazer. Caso pense em mais alguma incluo na resposta.

Answer (score 3):

Se o que se deseja é encontrar todos os registros onde o campo em questão tem o mesmo mês e ano da data atual, isso equivale a procurar valores maiores ou iguais ao primeiro dia do mês atual.

Podemos fazer isso assim:

```
SELECT
  titulo
, publicacao
FROM teste1
WHERE publicacao >= DATE_SUB( DATE( NOW() ), INTERVAL DAY( NOW() ) -1 DAY )
ORDER BY
  publicacao DESC
```

Apesar da aparente complexidade, se o campo dado for indexado, esse filtro será mais eficiente do que um feito buscando mês e ano separadamente, afinal este se beneficiará do índice.

Agora explicando por partes.

A expressão

```
DATE_SUB( NOW(), INTERVAL x DAY )
```

subtrai x dias de dia atual.

Para conseguirmos o primeiro dia do mês devemos subtrair da data atual o número do dia atual menos 1. Por exemplo: 28/08/2014 - 27 = 01/08/2014

Desta forma

```
DATE_SUB( NOW(), INTERVAL DAY( NOW() ) -1 DAY )
```

devolve o primeiro dia do mês.

Mas isso ainda não serve para o filtro que queremos, no caso do campo em questão ser um DATETIME, pois a hora atual pode ser maior que a hora de um registro do dia primeiro alterando o resultado que queremos da seleção.

Para evitar esse problema convertemos NOW() para DATE e chegamos à expressão que apresentei.

```
DATE_SUB( DATE( NOW() ), INTERVAL DAY( NOW() ) -1 DAY )
```

Comment: Bem observado o ponto dos índices.