# Consulta SQL retornar total de dias em um mês em duas datas

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tenho as seguintes tabelas:

**funcionario**:

- id_funcionario
- outras informações...

**histórico**:

- id_funcionario
- data_entrada
- data_saida

Tentei algumas *querys* mas não consegui obter o que eu queria. O que preciso é, depois de o usuário ter escolhido um mês, maio por exemplo, preciso retornar a quantidade de dias que aquele funcionário trabalho apenas em maio.

Por exemplo, caso o funcionário João tenha trabalhado do dia 25/05/2014 ao 03/06/2014 (no banco de dados está no formato certo) e o usuário tenha escolhido visualizar o histórico do funcionário João no mês de maio, apareça: 5 dias. Alguém podia ajudar com esta *query*?

```
SELECT DATEDIFF
(
    (SELECT historico.entrada FROM historico WHERE funcionario_id = 12) ,
    (SELECT historico.saida FROM historico WHERE funcionario_id = 12)
)
```

O que estou com dificuldade é como retornar apenas de um mês, em que lugar eu colocaria o `WHERE month(campo) = 05`?

Comment: Veja se [esta questão](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30891/13412), pode ajudar

Comment: Não :/, o problema é que eu posso ter datas que a entrada é no mês x, e a saída é no mês x+1. Por exemplo, Entrada 25/05/2014 e Saída 03/06/2014, e preciso dos dias do mês 05 por exemplo, o problema mesmo é quando é mês diferentes, porque se fossem com mês iguais serviria perfeitamente.

Comment: Do dia 25/05/2014 ao 31/05/2014 não são 6 dias de diferença?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Com a mudança de estratégia, fiz a edição da SQL para que calcule assim:

- Se os meses forem diferente ele faz dois cálculo do mês da entrada e do mês da saída.
- Se os meses tiverem diferenças de mais meses tipo mês 05 até o mês 07 você conseguiria então pegar o meio e fazer um cálculo no código PHP para descobrir tipo o mês 6 tem 30 dias igual está na SQL 1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12 tem 31 dias, o mês 2 dependendo do ano pode ter 28 ou 29 dias (pegue o `ano % 2 == 0` se for verdadeiro essa expressão tem 29 dias se não tem 28 dias), e os outros meses tem 30 dias.
- Se o mês informado pertencer a entrada pegue o campo `DIFERENCA_MENTRADA` se o mês informado pertence ao mês da saída pegue `DIFERENCA_MSAIDA`.

---

```
SELECT IF(mentrada <> msaida, 
       (
            CASE mentrada 
            WHEN (1 OR 3 OR 5 OR 7 OR 8 OR 10 OR 12) THEN
                DATEDIFF(date_format(concat(yentrada,'-', mentrada,'-', 31), '%Y-%m-%d'), data_entrada)             
            WHEN (2) THEN
                DATEDIFF(date_format(concat(yentrada,'-', mentrada,'-', IF(yentrada % 4 = 0,29,28)), '%Y-%m-%d'), data_entrada)
            ELSE
                DATEDIFF(date_format(concat(yentrada,'-', mentrada,'-', 30), '%Y-%m-%d'), data_entrada)             
            END         
        ), DATEDIFF(data_saida, data_entrada)) as diferenca_mentrada, 
        IF (mentrada <> msaida,
            DATEDIFF(data_saida, date_add(date_format(concat(ysaida,'-', msaida,'-1'), '%Y-%m-%d'), INTERVAL -1 DAY)),0) as diferenca_msaida,   
        id_funcionario, 
        data_entrada, 
        data_saida,
        mentrada,yentrada,
        msaida,ysaida
FROM  (
SELECT 
    id_funcionario,
    data_entrada, 
    data_saida, 
    month(data_entrada) mentrada, 
    year(data_entrada) yentrada,
    month(data_saida) msaida,
    year(data_saida) ysaida
FROM historico
) as historico WHERE (mentrada = 6 or msaida = 6) and yentrada = 2014 AND id_funcionario = 1
```

***Exemplo OnLine:*** [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6f202/12)

***Mês 5: Pegue então o diferenca_mentrada***

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

***Mês 6: Pegue então o diferenca_msaida***

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: A questão que mais me ajudou até agora foi essa. Mas ainda tenho um pequeno problema. Se eu escolho o mês 5, dá certinho. Mas e se eu escolher o mês 6? (Ainda tenho 3 dias trabalhados no mês 6) Ele não retorna o valor desejado, que é 3 dias. Tentei adaptar mas não deu certo.

Comment: Porque como relatado ele faz pela data_entrada @JoãoNeto, mas, dá para fazer um sub adaptação do que deseja. Concordo com seu posicionamento precisa fazer mais um item nessa SQL vou analisar e daqui a pouco eu coloco alguma coisa, OK!

Comment: Muito obrigado @Maria, também irei tentar aqui, caso conseguir aviso.

Comment: Isso, legal @JoãoNeto, vou fazer mais agora estou fora do computador mas, logo voltar eu faço...

Comment: Beleza, valeu Maria!

Comment: @JoãoNeto esse seria o mais próximo a sua realidade. Alguns dados deveram ser trabalhados no PHP.!

Comment: Consegui resolver a situação! Dei uma manipulada no PHP mas deu tudo certo! Valeuuu!

Answer (score 2):

Bom, não tenho certeza se compreendi sua dúvida, mas vamos la...

<sub>**QUERY**</sub>

```
SELECT DATEDIFF( '2014-06-03' , '2014-05-25' ) AS DIAS , ID FROM MYTABLE WHERE IDFUN = 1
```

<sub>**RESULTADO**</sub>

```
array( 'DIAS' => 9 , 'ID' => 1 )
```

Contou 9 dias pois foi o periodo entre 2014-06-03 e 2014-05-25.
É preciso formatar a data final.

---

> Caso o funcionário tenha trabalhado do dia 25/05/2014 ao 03/06/2014 e o usuário tenha escolhido visualizar o histórico do funcionário no mês de maio, apareça: 5 dias.

Você não pode aceitar a data fim no formato `03/06/2014`.
Recomendo formata para o ultimo dia do mês da data inicio para ter a consulta exatamente pelo mês selecionado: `Inicio: 25/05/2014 | Final: 31/05/2014`

---

Jogando a data final para o ultimo dia do mês referente à data inicio:

```
echo date( "t-m-Y" , strtotime( '2014-08-15' ) );
```

<sub>**RESULTADO**</sub>

```
31-08-2014
```

*Basta usar a data formatada na sua QUERY*

Answer (score 2):

Creio que o problema está na estrutura de dados adotada. Se deseja um histórico de trabalho realmente funcional e realista, vc deveria ter um registro por dia, onde junto ao registro teria a hora de entrada e a hora de saída.

Guardar o histórico por períodos como você apresentou em sua pergunta te dará trabalho e muitos problemas.

Mas uma possível solução é a seguinte

```
SELECT 
    DATEDIFF(
        IF( `saida` <= '2014-05-31', `saida`, '2014-05-31' ),
        IF( `entrada` >= '2014-05-01', `entrada`, '2014-05-01' )
    )
FROM `historico`
WHERE 
    `saida` <= '2014-05-31'
OR  `entrada` >= '2014-05-01'
WHERE `funcionario_id` = "1";
```

Evite funções do MySQL para calcular as datas utilizadas nos filtros, como `NOW()`, `CURDATE()`, etc, pois utilizando-as você terá uma perda de performance. Essas funções impossibilitam a utilização de cache de consultas pelo MySQL.

Como foi citado na resposta do @papa-charlie, para obter o último dia de um determinado mês, utilize em seu código PHP:

```
date( "t-m-Y" , strtotime( '2014-05-25' ) );
```

Se a estrutura estivesse na forma que citei acima, para conseguir o resultado que você deseja, bastaria filtrar o período desejado e contar o número de registros.

```
SELECT COUNT( `date` )
FROM historico
WHERE `date` between '2014-08-01' AND '2014-10-01'
```

Na sua estrutura atual, você pode ter problemas frequentes com esse calculo de datas, seja para relatórios anuais, mensais ou diários. Considere realizar agora a mudança da estrutura do seu sistema se ainda estiver em estágio inicial.

Comment: A minha estrutura tem que ser do jeito que tá, porque eu não registro os dias que o funcionário trabalhou, tenho que registrar o período, pois no meu sistema o admin insere a data de entrada e saída.

Comment: Entendi, você chegou atestar a minha primeira SQL? Fiz alguns testes aqui no meu computador funcionou tranquilo como vc cita na pergunta. Depois conferi ai.

Comment: No momento não to no pc, mas assim que chegar testarei e direi aqui. Valeu.

Comment: Muito obrigado! :)

Answer (score 1):

Cheguei ao resultado esperado verificando se a `data_saida` está no mesmo mês da data entrada através de um `IF` do `LAST_DAY` combinado com um `DATE_DIFF`:

```
SELECT *, 
last_day(data_entrada) as fim_mes,
DATEDIFF(IF(data_saida > last_day(data_entrada), last_day(data_entrada),data_saida), data_entrada) AS dias_trabalhados_mes 
FROM historico;
```

Com isso, basta combinar no final um `WHERE` com o `id` do funcionário e algo parecido com `month(data_entrada)`. Como mencionado pelo marcusagm, substituir `month(data_entrada)` por um `BETWEEN` pode ser uma boa idéia **se** existirem índices definidos na tabela.

Exemplo no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4acfb/3)

Comment: Chegou bem próximo do que eu queria, muito obrigado! :)